# View's color and Navigation Bar's color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I'm having a strange problem, the navigation bar and the view have the same exact UIColor, yet, the navigation bar looks darker! Why is that happening?

Note: I used this line of code in the `AppDelegate` inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common problem. You need to set

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Much appreciated.